# read QR code; error: cannot find symbol variable AppConstants

Tags: android, qr-code

I copied a code to read QRCode through camera and get the text; but I get compilation error-> error: cannot find symbol variable AppConstants. Also I do not understand why intent is needed in handleResult() and how to get back the result text of QR code. I suppose result.getText() gives the result text. But how to use that? Is there any better example?

error->

```
 error: cannot find symbol
        intent.putExtra(AppConstants.KEY_QR_CODE, result.getText());
                        ^
  symbol:   variable AppConstants
  location: class QRScannerActivity
```

CODE:

```
public class QRScannerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {
    private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_q_r_scanner);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
        setContentView(mScannerView);

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
        mScannerView.startCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mScannerView.stopCamera();

    }
    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result result) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra(AppConstants.KEY_QR_CODE, result.getText());
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your error log with  this?

Comment: posted the error, please see the post

Comment: simply import  the AppConstants class to your activity or declare AppConstants.KEY_QR_CODE